# UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate being deinitialized immediately after it is presented

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipresentationcontroller

I'm trying to present a view controller modally with a custom presenter using `UIPresentationController` (and `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`).

The problem is that **the transitioning delegate is being deinitialized immediately after `animationController(presented:presenting:source:)` is called.** This means `animationController(dismissed:)` never gets called - and thus, a dismissal animation cannot be set.

In the end, I want to be able to define the dismissal animation. I believe what I explained above is the root of the problem, but can't find anything about this online.

---

Here is my implementation of `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`:

```
final class Manager: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    private let size: CGSize
    var animator: Animator

    init(size: CGSize) {
        self.size = size
        self.animator = Animator(duration: 0.4, loaf: loaf)
    }

    deinit {
        print("DEINIT") // 2) Then this is being called immediately after
    }

    func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
        return Controller(
            presentedViewController: presented,
            presenting: presenting,
            size: size
        )
    }

    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        animator.presenting = true
        return animator // 1) This is called first after the view controller is presented
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        animator.presenting = false
        return animator // 3) This is never called
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm setting the transitioning delegate:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func presentModally(_ viewController: UIViewController, size: CGSize) {
        viewController.transitioningDelegate = Manager(size: size)
        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        present(viewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

---

When the view controller is then dismissed, the view always defaults to being pushed down and disappearing. Again, `animationController(dismissed:)` is never called and I can't figure out why.

Comment: You need a strong reference since the transitioningDelegate property is weak.

Comment: @maddy Where would the strong reference be kept?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by storing a reference to the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` on the presenting view controller. Then, when presenting the modal, set it like this:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func presentModally(_ viewController: UIViewController, size: CGSize) {
        viewController.transDelegate = Manager(size: size)
        viewController.transitioningDelegate = viewController.transDelegate
        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        present(viewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```